# How to show message in grid with table?

Tags: java, swt

I created a grid with TableViewer.

In some cases, I want to hide the TableViewer and to a show message.

This is how I created the TableViewer :

```
gridLayout = new GridLayout();
Table table = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL |      SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER )
table.setLayoutData(gridLayout)
```

I know how to hide the table -  table.setVisible(false). The issue is where to set the message? I didn't create a textBox (SWT) for this.

Do I need to create textBox (SWT) and to set the visible for false ( as default ) and only when I want to show message to show it as visible = true ?

Comment: Yes ;) This is a way you can do it

Answer (score 0):

In that manner you could as you say.  Here is some code a little more drawn up.

```
// The parents layout of message and table viewer
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
parent.setLayout(gridLayout);

// The message widget
Text message = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
message.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL 
 GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL));

// The table viewer
TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL |      SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER );
Table table = viewer.getTable();

// Layout for table
GridData gridData = new GridData();
// fill in your grid data setup here
// EX: gridData.verticalAlignemnt = GridData.FILL;
// end fill
viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
```